# "Special Epic Cohorts" explanation

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

So, the Epic Leadership feat contains a list of "Special Epic Cohorts." These include such things as dragons and 12-headed hydra. Now, to my understanding Cohort selection was typically limited to beings that had an LA. But the 12-headed Hydra, for example, is listed as a lvl 19 Cohort somehow… with no explanation.

Does anyone have

1. a complete list of "special epic cohorts" since the one in the SRD is listed as merely an example list, and
2. any idea of how they calculate these things?

Comment: Just so no one else need do the research, while the *Dragon* #293 article "Monsters with Class" (52) does give every *3e* creature from that  *Monster Manual* an ECL, the  article's ECLs don't jibe with the epic cohort list *and* the article predates the *3.5* revision therefore the *3.5* update of the feat Epic Leadership from *Power of Faerûn* 155 and 156. (Don't dismay if you ain't got *PF* — the feat's pretty much the same as the original except it's missing  the epic cohort list.)

Answer (score 1):

Just because no Level Adjustment is given in a creatures initial entry doesn't mean one can't be added in later.  The epic cohort list gives level adjustment values for cohorts that players can use via the epic leadership rules, if they'd like.  Some GMs may allow players to use those level adjustment assignments for other purposes as well.  Like most level adjustment and challenge rating stuff, the values given are basically arbitrary and don't hew strictly to any particular rationale.  The SRD list is complete: the list in the book is just a list of examples with the expectation that in epic play the player would just tell the DM 'I wanna [X] as my cohort' and the DM would say 'Ok, an [X] should be level adjustment [arbitrary number in line with those given] plus hit dice'.